# MySQL Create Table by Select alternative?

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am trying to create MySQL query, for example instead of

```
CREATE TABLE query_table ENGINE=MYISAM
SELECT 
DISTINCT
g.gameid,
g.image, 
g.title,
FROM scores AS s
INNER JOIN games AS g
ON(s.gameid = g.gameid)
INNER JOIN user AS u
ON(s.userid = u.user_id)
ORDER BY s.time DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

is there something like truncate and inserting the select like

```
TRUNCATE TABLE query_table ENGINE=MYISAM
INSERT 
SELECT DISTINCT
g.gameid,
g.image, 
g.title,
FROM scores AS s
INNER JOIN games AS g
ON(s.gameid = g.gameid)
INNER JOIN user AS u
ON(s.userid = u.user_id)
ORDER BY s.time DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

to speed it up? Because I am trying to create temporary tables to save it as cache for about 5 minutes and recreate it again.

Comment: If you want temporary tables, use `create temporary table`.

Comment: Why not just do two commands? `TRUNCATE TABLE query_table`, then `INSERT INTO query_table SELECT ...`? Also, as @jordanm points out, use temporary tables, not MyISAM.

Comment: @jordanm Temporary tables are useless because it will be dropped automatcaly and I need to create a cache table that will last and that can be queried by others too.